# Find the prime factorization of $X^3-5X^2+6X+7$ in $(\Bbb{Z}/11\Bbb{Z})[x]$.

Tags: number-theory

Find the prime factorization of  $X^3-5X^2+6X+7$ in $(\Bbb{Z}/11\Bbb{Z})[x]$. 
I try doing this with analogy to the integers but I think I am not sure what is prime and what is isn't. I could really use help.

Comment: It's a third-degree polynomial, which means it can be factored iff it has a root. That is as true modulo $11$ as it is over the integers, rationals and the reals.

Comment: In particular, it is irreducible if it is relatively prime to $x^7-x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every polynomial of degree two or three over a field is reducible iff has a factor of degree one.

Try to find a root to your polynomial, if you doesn't secceed, the polynomial is irreducible. Observe that cheking for solutions is to use a complete residue set modulo $11$ for values of the polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

You can check $-2$ is a root in $\mathbf Z/11\mathbf Z$,and the quotient by $X+2$, which is $X^2+4X-2$, has no root since it would satisfy  $\,(x+2)^2=-5$, whereas the list of squares is $\,0,1,4,-2,5,3$.

Hence the factorisation  is:
$$(X+2)(X^2+4X-2). $$